# webRTC ReadyState error in ios

Tags: ios, webrtc, kurento

**What I Did?**

I am new to webRTC. I had download a demo from the link `https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios`

I'm using kurento server for communicating the device and the browser.

Encountered an error while connecting the browser and the device.
I'm getting an error

```
"WebSocket closed with code: 1001 reason:Stream end encountered wasClean:0" and always I'm getting ReadyState = SR_CLOSED.
```

How to resolve this? pls suggest some solution.

*****What I Want?*****

How to change the ReadyState to SR_open?
How to open the connection of WebSocket?

Comment: Is your KMS running?

Comment: KMS is working fine ,but the application server(nodejs) which i am using crashed showing the following error
**server.js:543
return callback('Error getting Receiver');
      ^
ReferenceError: callback is not defined**

Comment: @Murugesh Well then you better go catch it! ;). But jokes aside, can you post your code around that line? It seems some function wants to call a callback, but you didn't supply one.